# Extract software from multiple archives with WinRAR

Tags: windows-xp, winrar

I downloaded some software that was split in five parts that I cannot extract using WinRAR.

Each part is around 110 MB. The file format of each part is **.zip**. I have extracted all the parts in a separate folder. In each there is an .exe file of that software and therefore, there are five .exe files in total. When I try to open it, it says

> The application failed to initialize properly

The files are in the format:

- Software1.rar zip
- Software2.rar zip, etc.

How do I extract these files using WinRAR?

Comment: Can you please copy the actual name of the file and reply to to this comment with it. Or to be easier a screen shot of the files on your pc

Comment: You had lost your account, but I have now merged it so you have ownership of the question again - you might wish to consider registering so this doesn't happen in the future. Please add any updates as an edit to your question.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 9):

Just put all the parts in the same folder, then unzip the first part and winrar will automatically recognize the others and attach them.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm)

First you must make sure you have the full set of the rar files. It will start from filename.part01.rar and end with filename.part21.rar (if the total is 21 files).

Then right click on the filename.part01.rar and select "extract here". Notice the extracted file is much large than all 21 rar file combined. That means you had successfully extract it.

Comment: No guarantee that they will be named that way. In this case the OP specified that it was zip files and I have had multipart rar archives named `.rar`, `.r01` `.r02` and so on.  Just start unraring the *first* file (you can usually figure it out from the file names) and winrar should automaticly find the next rar/zip it needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler than you would think. For multiple zip files that are split, you can recombine them with the copy command:

```
copy /b "file1.zip"+"file2.zip"+"file3.zip"+"file4.zip" "NewZippedName.zip"
```

Symantec uses this for many downloads, but they always include a batch file to do it for you.